# Is it possible to set appirater to show after every nth days?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appirater

I am interested to use:
https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater

And I am talking about iOS version of it.

Is it possible to set appirater to show after every nth days or something like that?
Like on some regular interval every nth days or even 25 start of app.

I am thinking there is some way to show it after nth time with some occurrence.

All example on website show how to show it after some days or after some starts.
So I suspect that if user do not review app then it will just not show ever again.

Comment: You have the source code to the appirater. Change it to work however you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out this open-source tool UAAppReviewManager which is an another approach to Appirater. 
[UAAppReviewManager](https://github.com/urbanapps/UAAppReviewManager)

And you can set the number of days to show the alert view for rating your app by setting this method :

```
+ (void)setDaysBeforeReminding:(NSUInteger)daysBeforeReminding;
```

Comment: for aspirator is not possible to shown evern n soothing time. Author twitted me.